# retrieve generic type to call generic method

Tags: c#, entity-framework, reflection

I need to call the generic Method Filter in order to perform a selection in a Entity Framework database table.

```
IEnumerable<T> x = Filter<T>(_cust, conditions, value_conditions);
```

T could be any table of my database. 
Using reflection i can execute the Filter method:

```
MethodInfo methodFilter = typeof(SearchTool).GetMethod("Filter");
mI = methodFilter.MakeGenericMethod(eObject);
IEnumerable<T> x = mI.Invoke(this, new object[] { allElements, conditions, value_conditions });
```

"*SearchTool*" is the name of the namespace where the Filter function is declared.
In order to define T in the Filter generic method, i declared the parameter eObject which is a Type object defined as follow:

```
eObject = Type.GetType("SearchApplication.Customers");
```

"*SearchApplication*" is the namespace where the database table named "Customers" is defined. Customers is an EntityObject.

The question is: Are there any other possibilities to retrieve the Type of a EF EntityObject instead of declare a string like "SearchApplication.Customers" ??

Thanks in advance
Paolo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `typeof`:

```
var type = typeof(SearchApplication.Customers);
```

Comment: Yes, ok you're right! But what about retrieve it from an instance, for example northwindEntities.Customers.(something else)???? Note that northwindEntities is the ObjectContext

Comment: @rebe21: In that case you can use `GetType()`: `northwindEntities.Customers.GetType();`

Comment: @rebe21: Ah, yes. You need to extract the type. Without any error checking, it would look like so: `northwindEntities.Customers.GetType().GetGenericArguments()[0];`

Comment: Yes!!! You got it!!! Thanks a lot @Daniel Hilgarth!! It's what i was looking for!!